# Jquery Image Gallery with Vertical thumbnail Navigation?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I am looking for a Jquery image gallery which have vertical thumbnail like at the following page.

http://realtyexecutivesofnewyork.com/product_detail.php?ml_num=2275875.

Can anybody point out me to something similar jquery solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) is by far the best plugin for this sort of thing, [this is what you want](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html)

If you need a hand setting it up, just shout.

Comment: Alex thanks for your answer, but I am not good in Jquery. I was asking if there is some solution available. If you any idea, share with us.

Comment: @kakaajee, I have shared my idea 'jCarousel'

Answer (score 0):

The site you are referring uses, a vertical menu scroll plugin

perhaps this [one](http://realtyexecutivesofnewyork.com/script/jquery.scrollit-menu2.js).

and the code is somewhat like this

```
$('.myMenu').scrollIt({
         scrollDuration : 250,
         scrollItwrapper : 'myMenuScroll'
    });    

});
```

And on clicking that link, it just changes the `src` attribute of img element, and loads the image (No wonder if your internet connection is slow, you will see that image take a lot to load).

You will find more better at [here](http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/).

Comment: Thanks for the code link, but I was asking for Jquery plugin similar to this one, and the link of the examples don't have any vertical thumbnail scroller

Comment: @kakaajee, you want jCarousel, check my answer.